# Burn AVI file to DVD on Linux

Tags: linux, conversion, dvd, burning, avi

What is the most streamlined process in **Linux** for getting a high quality .AVI file burned to DVD disk for playback on normal DVD players?

Comment: High quality? DVD can only hold 480p

Answer (score 4):

[Convert Xvid or Avi to DVD Format in Ubuntu](http://www.ivankristianto.com/2009/05/tutorial-convert-xvid-or-avi-to-dvd-format-in-ubuntu/),
also the Ubuntuforums thread [Convert AVI to DVD ISO](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=933797).
<sub>Also read through the comments for more references (like, DeVeDe)</sub>.

Here is one more article I located recently when trying to backup an Audio CD:
[The Ultimate Guide To Manage Your Audio/Video Files In Linux](http://maketecheasier.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-manage-your-audiovideo-files-in-linux/2009/03/03)
a nice reference for multiple related tools.

Answer (score 4):

If you're talking about a front-end GUI app, look at [Devede](http://www.rastersoft.com/programas/devede.html).

Comment: Good directions on how to do it using Devede here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-create-video-dvds.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Avidemux**](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) (Available for Linux and Windows).

Detailed video on converting to DVD format [**here**](http://mulder.dummwiedeutsch.de/etc/adm_wink/avi2dvd.htm). You'll also want the [**DVD authoring guide**](http://avidemux.org/admForum/viewtopic.php?id=3570).

Answer (score 1):

define 'normal' DVD-Player.

DivX support is pretty much standard for set top boxes today, so burning your AVI file(s) onto a data DVD should suffice.

Comment: Watch out for the length of your filename if you choose this option.  Some set top boxes refuse to recognize files if the filename is too long.

Answer (score 1):

Tovid might be what you're looking for. Here's an [example](http://tovid.wikia.com/wiki/Simple_example)

```
tovid mpg -in ski_trip.mov -out ski_trip
tovid mpg -in florida.mov -out florida
tovid mpg -in recital.mov -out recital
tovid menu "Steamboat Ski Weekend" "Florida Beach Vacation" "My Piano Recital" -out main_menu
tovid xml -menu main_menu.mpg ski_trip.mpg florida.mpg recital.mpg -out my_dvd
tovid dvd -burn my_dvd.xml
```

Here's a link to the [Tovid wiki](http://tovid.wikia.com/wiki/Tovid_Wiki) which has details on installing and setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

If your AVI file is encoded in Divx or Xvid you might want to try burning just the file. DivX playback is a popular feature on DVD players these days... yours might support it without you even knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely stream-lined, but [a way to do it](http://www.howtoadvice.com/UbuntuDVD):

> Open DeVeDe from the Ubuntu Menut at: Applications > Sound & Video >
>   DeVeDe
>
> Select "Video DVD" from DeVeDe's menu.
>
> To name the DVD title, click the "Properties" button, in the "Title"
>   section. I like my videos to reply after they're done, so I select the
>   "Play First Title" option. Click the "OK" button
>
> In the "Files" section of DeVeDe, click the "Add" button. A window
>   will pop up. Under the "File" section click the folder icon (on the
>   right), and navigate to where the AVI file is (that you created
>   earlier using Avidemux). Click the "OK" button. If you want to add
>   additional avi files, you can repeat this step as needed.
>
> Under the "Menu" section, I always uncheck "Create a Menu with
>   Subtitles", because I like the DVD to just start playing when I put it
>   into my player (without the additional that a menu offers).
>
> Now click the forward button, and choose were you want your DVD Iso to
>   be placed on your file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.